# Custom Rewrite Rule in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a custom page in Wordpress with a special URL Rewrite and I am trying the following:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('^services/service-in-([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=238&location=$matches[1]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

However, when I go to domain.com/services/service-in-london/ I just get a 404 message.

I have also tried this manually in htaccess but just get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%location%', '([^/]*)');

    add_rewrite_rule('^services/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=238&location=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```